# Clarification about ios and android push and ionic

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push

This may sounds stupid, but after I read a lot about this topic Im still a little bit confusing about push.

To me there are 2 kind of push:

```
1 - When your phone is idle and suddenly an "alert" pops up in the phone telling you something has happened with your app
2 - When you are "inside" the app and you get notified about something (maybe a new user joined the chat in a chat application)
```

After been testing and reading the documentation for ionic push

```
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview
```

Im still not sure if ionic push provide #1 or #2.

They say a lot about APNs (which I understand has to do with #1) but then when I read the quick star here:

```
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start
```

Then it states that:

```
"Once you have both details, make sure your application is OPEN and then use the following cURL request to send a push. Replace the highlighted text with your own values."
```

Huh? So ionic push is about push sent to your active application? Not when it is idle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The qucik start guide also has this part in it :

> 3. TELL YOUR APP TO USE LIMITED PUSHES
>
> Limited pushes aren't native push notifications, and are meant for
>   testing against our API. They'll work in a browser or emulator, but
>   won't arrive when your app is minimized, and the tokens won't last
>   more than 2 hours.
>
> To configure your app to use full featured push notifications, follow
>   the Full Setup guide.

So this setups something they call "limited pushes" which work only with open app. In order to setup traditional pushes, you need to follow the [Full Setup guide](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-full-setup)